# Java HTTP Server file upload implementation problem

Tags: java, html, http, httpserver

I have been working on creating a Java HTTP server that serves a basic HTML page to a browser client. The server is hosted at **`http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload`**. However, I've encountered challenges when trying to implement a file upload feature. I have been unable to find comprehensive tutorials or guides on how to correctly handle binary file uploads that are easy enough to understand within in this specific context.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class HTTP {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = 8080;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        System.out.println("Server started on port " + port);

        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            handleRequest(clientSocket);
        }
    }

    private static void handleRequest(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        
        // Read the HTTP request
        StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            request.append(line).append("\r\n");
        }
        
        // Find the content length from the request headers
        int contentLength = getContentLength(request.toString());

        OutputStream outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        if (request.toString().contains("/upload")) {
            // Respond with an HTML page containing the upload form
            sendHtmlResponse(out, getUploadPage());
        } else if (request.toString().contains("/upFile")) {
            // Handle file upload
            saveUploadedFile(clientSocket.getInputStream(), contentLength);
            sendHtmlResponse(out, getUploadSuccessPage());
        } else {
            // Respond with a default message
            sendHtmlResponse(out, getDefaultPage());
        }

        clientSocket.close();
    }

    private static void sendHtmlResponse(PrintWriter out, String content) {
        out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Content-Length: " + content.length());
        out.println();
        out.println(content);
        out.flush();
    }

    private static void saveUploadedFile(InputStream inputStream, int contentLength) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Getting uploaded file to save.");
        String line;
        String fileName = "null";
        int strike = 0;
        StringBuilder boundary = new StringBuilder();
        ByteArrayOutputStream fileContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
        // Read the request headers until an empty line is encountered
        while ((line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            if (line.contains("WebKitFormBoundary")) strike++;
            System.out.println("In a while loop.");
            System.out.println(line); // Debug: Print the incoming line
            if (strike == 2) break;
            if (!line.contains("WebKitFormBoundary") && !line.contains("Content-Disposition") && !line.contains("Content-Type:")) {
                boundary.append(line);
                System.out.println("Adding " + line);
            }
            if (line.startsWith("Content-Disposition: form-data;")) {
                String[] parts = line.split("; ");
                for (String part : parts) {
                    if (part.startsWith("filename=")) {
                        String[] filenameParts = part.split("=");
                        String filename = filenameParts[1].replace("\"", "");
                        fileName = filename;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        
        // Read the file content based on the provided content length
        while (totalBytesRead < contentLength && (bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileContent.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        }
        
        saveBytesToFile(fileContent.toByteArray(), fileName);
    }
    
    private static int getContentLength(String request) {
        int startIndex = request.indexOf("Content-Length:") + 15;
        int endIndex = request.indexOf("\r\n", startIndex);
        String contentLengthStr = request.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        return Integer.parseInt(contentLengthStr.trim());
    }
    
    private static void saveBytesToFile(byte[] content, String filename) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Saving file.");

        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//" + filename);
        System.out.println("Path: " + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.toAbsolutePath().toString())) {
            fos.write(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle exception here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("File saved: " + filename);
    }

    private static String getUploadPage() {
        return "<html><body><form action=\"/upFile\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n" +
               "  <input type=\"file\" name=\"file\"/><br/>\n" +
               "  <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\"/>\n" +
               "</form></body></html>";
    }

    private static String getUploadSuccessPage() {
        return "<html><body><h1>File uploaded successfully!</h1></body></html>";
    }

    private static String getDefaultPage() {
        return "<html><body><h1>Welcome to the Simple HTTP Server</h1></body></html>";
    }
```

I have made some code a while ago in which txt files worked for the most part but it would corrupt other files. It seems that my implementation here does not know when to stop and I would need to stop the tab from loading to save anything. Perhaps I have poorly implemented this.

Comment: You need a 'binary' file with an absolutely known content that you can check afterwards. Don't accumulate in a BOS first - write it straight to file or it's not scalable

Comment: The main noticeable problem is that you're attempting to read Content-Length before it's even been sent and you attempt to process it whether it's present or not